# make a background image full screen in landscape iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to  make a background image full screen in landscape iPhone.In iPhone simulator,the image appeared,but isn't full screen.Here is my code

```
CGSize size=[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
[self addChild:backgroundImage z:0 tag:0];
NSLog(@"size.height %f,size.width %f,image.width %f,image.height %f",size.height,size.width,backgroundImage.contentSize.width,backgroundImage.contentSize.height);
```

Xcode output
size.height 480.000000,size.width 320.000000,image.width 480.000000,image.height 320.000000
And I know iPhone is 480*320 points.Why is the image not full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you placed hd image for retina display and proper position.

```
backgroundImage.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f);
backgroundImage.position = ccp(size.width*0.5f, size.height*0.5f);
```

Comment: Thank you.I know why now.That't because my simulator is landscape and I didn't set image's position properly.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 4s and later have retina displays which are twice the resolution your mention. You can disable this in cocos2d in your appdelegate, but all this will do is stretch all of your images to double automatically. the best thing to do is have retina sized versions of all of your images and append "-hd" to the file names. cocos2d will do the rest. also be aware that the new iphone 5 has yet a screen 3rd size which you will have to account for.